# Latex character in R graphics?

Tags: r, latex

I have learned latex to write reports and my thesis. I am using R a lot more for  graphics. I was wondering: is there a way to change the font in R graphs to make them look more "latex-like"? I would like to include these graphs into latex documents. Thank you!

Comment: Did you at least search? For example, in your favorite web browser, something like "R: computer modern"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some good libraries out there for R and Tex, but if you're looking to change the font you should check out library(extrafont)

For example, if you're looking to use Garamond in your plots, you can do:

```
library(extrafont)

pdf("plot_garamond.pdf", family="Garamond", width=4, height=4.5)

plot(mtcars$mpg, mtcars$wt, 
 main = "Fuel Efficiency of 32 Cars",
 xlab = "Weight (x1000 lb)",
 ylab = "Miles per Gallon")

dev.off()
```

More info at http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2012/09/how-to-use-your-favorite-fonts-in-r-charts.html

And the library instructions are at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/extrafont/extrafont.pdf